# C++ Bad access when assigning an element to map value

Tags: c++, dictionary, hashmap, exc-bad-access

So the question explains the problem...

### Background:

I'm trying to solve [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/attribute-parser/problem) from HackerRank.

It's basically an html tag parser. Valid input guaranteed, attributes are strings only.

### My Approach

I created a custom `Tag` class that can store a `map<string,Tag>` of other `Tag`'s, as well as a `map<string,string>` of attributes. The parsing seems to be working correctly.

### The Problem

During the querying part, I get a `BAD_ACCESS` error on the following query/html combo:

```
4 1
<a value = "GoodVal">
<b value = "BadVal" size = "10">
</b>
</a>
a.b~size
```

The error occurs when I try to access the `b` Tag from `a`. Specifically, it's in the `t=t.tags[tag_name]`, Line 118 below.

### Code

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

class Tag {
public:
    Tag(){};
    Tag(string name):name(name){};
    string name;
    map<string,Tag> tags = map<string, Tag>();
    map<string,string> attribs=map<string,string>();
};

int main() {
    int lines, queries;
    std::cin>>lines>>queries;

    std:string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    stack<string> open;
    auto tags = map<string, Tag>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        getline(cin, str);
        if (str.length()>1){
            // If it's not </tag>, then it's an opening tag
            if  (str[1] != '/') {
                // Parse tag name
                auto wordidx = str.find(" ");
                if (wordidx == -1) {
                    wordidx = str.length()-1.f;
                }
                string name = str.substr(1,wordidx-1);
                auto t = Tag(name);

                string sub = str.substr(wordidx);
                auto equalidx=sub.find("=");

                // Parse Attributes
                while (equalidx != std::string::npos) {
                    string key = sub.substr(1,equalidx-2);
                    sub = sub.substr(equalidx);
                    auto attrib_start = sub.find("\"");
                    sub = sub.substr(attrib_start+1);
                    auto attrib_end = sub.find("\"");
                    string val = sub.substr(0, attrib_end);
                    sub = sub.substr(attrib_end+1);

                    t.attribs[key] = val;
                    equalidx=sub.find("=");
                }

                // If we're in a tag, push to that, else push to the base tags
                if (open.size() == 0) {
                    tags[name] = t;
                } else {
                    tags[open.top()].tags[name]=t;
                }
                open.push(name);
            } else {
                // Pop the stack if we reached a closing tag
                auto wordidx = str.find(">");
                string name = str.substr(2,wordidx-2);

                // Sanity check, but we're assuming valid input
                if (name.compare(open.top())) {
                    cout<<"FUCK"<<name<<open.top()<<endl;
                    return 9;
                }
                open.pop();
            }

        } else {
            std::cout<<"FUCK\n";
        }
    }

    //
    // Parse in queries
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < queries; i++) {
        getline(cin, str);
        Tag t = Tag();
        bool defined = false;


        auto next_dot = str.find(".");
        while (next_dot!=string::npos) {
            string name = str.substr(0,next_dot);
            if (defined && t.tags.find(name) == t.tags.end()) {
                //TAG NOT IN T
                cout<<"Not Found!"<<endl;
                continue;
            }
            t = !defined ? tags[name] : t.tags[name];
            defined = true;

            str = str.substr(next_dot+1);
            next_dot = str.find(".");
        }

        auto splitter = str.find("~");
        string tag_name = str.substr(0,splitter);
        string attrib_name = str.substr(splitter+1);

        if (!defined) {
            t = tags[tag_name];
        } else if (t.tags.find(tag_name) == t.tags.end()) {
            //TAG NOT IN T
            cout<<"Not Found!"<<endl;
            continue;
        } else {
            t = t.tags[tag_name];
        }
        // T is now set, check the attribute
        if (t.attribs.find(attrib_name) == t.attribs.end()) {
            cout<<"Not Found!"<<endl;
        } else {
            cout<<t.attribs[attrib_name]<<endl;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

### What I've tried

This is fixed by just defining `Tag x = t.tags[tag_name];` in the line above as a new variable, and then doing `t = x;` but why is this even happening?

Also, the following query also then fails: `a.b.c~height`, but it fails on Line 99 when it tried to get a.tags["b"]. No idea why. I was gonna just go with the hacky fix above, but this seems like a big core issue that i'm doing wrong.

I would suggest running this on an IDE and verifying that the parsing is indeed correct.

Comment: Just having a quick look at your code, the only possibility for "bad access" is mishandling of your strings and assuming you're accessing the string within bounds.  I doubt it has anything to do with `std::map`.  For example you do `find()`, but never check if anything was found, you assume strings have at least 2 characters when you have `string[1]`, etc.  In addition to all that, you stick one gigantic piece of code in `main` instead of breaking up the code into logical functions, thus make things easier to unit test.  Why isn't the code to determine if `<\tag>` exists a separate function?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this is interview prep, so the goal for me was to get something out asap. I understand style is horrible, but the string parsing is correct, and I debugged the code, and the string key is also correct. So I think this is a memory issue, because I do check if the key is found in the map before access using `if (t.tags.find(tag_name) == t.tags.end())`

Comment: Give us an example text that causes the issue, and I will bet you that your string parsing fails.

Comment: "this is interview prep, so the goal for me was to get something out asap" - You don't think interviewers evaluate you on the quality of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t=t.tags[tag_name]
```

This expression is unsafe because you are copy-assigning an object that is owned by that object over the owning object.

Consider what happens on this line:

1. The map lookup is performed and returns a `Tag&`.
2. You try to copy-assign this to `t`, invoking the implicit copy-assigment operator.
3. This operator copy-assigns `t.tags` from the `tags` attribute of the copy source -- *which lives in `t.tags`.*

The result is that the object you're copying into `t` is destroyed in the middle of that copy.  This causes undefined behavior, and an immediate crash is honestly the *best possible outcome* as it told you exactly where the problem was.  (This kind of problem frequently manifests at some point later in the program, at which point you've lost the state necessary to figure out what caused the UB.)

One workaround would be to move the source object into a temporary and then move-assign that temporary over `t`:

```
t = Tag{std::move(t.tags[tag_name])};
```

This lifts the data we want to assign to `t` *out of `t`* before we try to put it in `t`.  Then, when `t`'s assignment operator goes to replace `t.tags`, the data you're trying to assign to `t` doesn't live there anymore.

However, this overall approach involves a lot of unnecessary copying. It would be better to declare `t` as `Tag const *t;` instead -- have it be a *pointer* to a tag.  Then you can just move that pointer around to point at other tags in your data structure without making copies.

---

Side note: I just did this problem the other day!  Here's a hint that might help you simplify things: do you actually need a structure of tags?  Is there a simpler type of lookup structure that would work instead of nested tags?

Comment: Ok, so I got it working (3 hours later, and only because of your help). First things first: thanks a lot! Second, what would be a simpler lookup structure? There has to be some understanding of parental path... Would coding the parental path as a string work? So that the map would be `map<string,map<string,string>>` and the key is the entire path as a string (which I can make on the fly during creation) right??

Comment: You hit on it in the last part of your comment -- you can build the lookup key for each _attribute_ (not just element) on the fly, so the only structure you need is `std::map<std::string, std::string>`.

Comment: I should clarify that's the only lookup structure you need to execute the queries. Of course, you need a stack to maintain the nested tag state while building that structure.

Comment: Of course, essentially the top part of the code remains the same (more or less) except for how I key the attributes, then the queries are basically an instant operation. I love the idea!

Comment: You could also use `std::hash_map` for O(1) lookup (instead of `std::map`'s O(log n)) but the map may take longer to build, so it depends on difference between the number of queries and the tag data structure size.

Comment: I think `hash_map` is better in all cases correct? It's O(1) on average for insertion+lookup. Which means the entire code will run in O(m+q) where m+q are the lines and queries. I haven't coded in C++ for years, so it's taking me some time to remember all the data structures. I love the suggestions though, feel free to give more!

Comment: `std::hash_map` doesn't need to keep the tree sorted/balanced but it does have to hash each item (for insertion _and_ lookup). For very small test cases, one might be significantly faster than the other and it's hard to say without actually benchmarking. It's probably a micro-optimization anyway, considering the size of HR's test cases.

Comment: That's fair. I completely agree. Most of the queries/tag structures in test cases are well within reason so the hash time isn't too big of a consideration.